# Expand nested data (json, Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Consider a snippet of a

```
{
    "participant_id": 37,
    "response_date": "2016-05-19T07:19:32.620Z",
    "data": {
        "summary": 8,
        "q6": [
            "1",
            "2"
        ],
        "q1": 0,
        "q2": 1,
        "q3": 1,
        "q4": 2,
        "q5": 2
    }
}, 
{
    "participant_id": 37,
    "response_date": "2016-05-26T07:14:24.7130Z",
    "data": {
        "summary": 8,
        "q6": [
            "1",
            "2",
            "4"
        ],
        "q1": 0,
        "q2": 1,
        "q3": 1,
        "q4": 2,
        "q5": 2
    }
}
```

which will produce a Pandas data frame:

```
        0   q1   q2   q3   q4   q5         q6  summary    participant_id           response_date
672   NaN  0.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0     [1, 2]      8.0                37 2016-05-19 07:19:32.620
711   NaN  0.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  [1, 2, 4]      7.0                37 2016-05-26 07:14:24.713
```

How to expand the nested `q6` to a 'wider' format? There are up to 4 possible values, that this attribute `q6` may contain. So, ideally it should be:

```
            0   q1   q2   q3   q4   q5   q6   q7   q8   q9   summary    participant_id           response_date
    672   NaN  0.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0       8.0                37 2016-05-19 07:19:32.620
    711   NaN  0.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0       7.0                37 2016-05-26 07:14:24.713
```

So, basically, the numbers in the square bracket encode the position of `1` in 4 element array.

Is there a simple Pandasian solution?

**EDIT**

Some entries are mistakenly reversed or randomly recorded (1st and 3rd rows):

```
        0   q1   q2   q3   q4   q5      q6  summary    participant_id           response_date
672   NaN  0.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  [1, 2]      8.0               37 2016-05-19 07:19:32.620
711   NaN  0.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0     [1]      7.0               37 2016-05-20 07:14:24.713
740   NaN  0.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  [2, 1]      8.0               37 2016-05-21 07:10:17.251
774   NaN  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  3.0  [1, 2]      8.0               37 2016-05-22 08:28:14.579
809   NaN  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  3.0  [1, 2]      8.0               37 2016-05-23 07:30:27.259
```

They should be sorted before any further manipulations are performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not so easy.

- [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) + [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) for new df
- [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for adding missing values + `rename` columns
- [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to original, (`q6`) column is removed
- [`startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) + [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html) for new order of columns

---

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(df['q6'].values.tolist()), prefix_sep='', prefix='')
df1.columns = df1.columns.astype(int)
df1 =df1.reindex(columns=range(1,5),fill_value=0).rename(columns=lambda x: 'q{}'.format(x+5))
print (df1)
   q6  q7  q8  q9
0   1   1   0   0
1   1   1   0   1
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([df.drop('q6', axis=1), df1], axis=1)
mask = df.columns.str.startswith('q', na=False)
cols1 = df.columns[mask].tolist()
cols2 = df.columns[~mask].tolist()
cols = cols2[:1] + cols1 + cols2[1:]

df = df.reindex_axis(cols, axis=1)
print (df)
    0  q1  q2  q3  q4  q5  q6  q7  q8  q9  summary  participant_id  \
0 NaN   0   1   1   2   2   1   1   0   0        8              37   
1 NaN   0   1   1   2   2   1   1   0   1        8              37   

               response_date  
0   2016-05-19T07:19:32.620Z  
1  2016-05-26T07:14:24.7130Z
```

Comment: thanks! I have several typos in my database, some entries are in reverse order, for example, instead of [1,2], they are [2,1], or [1,4,2]. Is there a simple solution to sort them?

Comment: I think [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) would work -  `df1.reindex(columns=range(1,5),fill_value=0).sort_index(axis=1).rename(columns=lambda x: 'q{}'.format(x+5))`

Comment: it doesn't work. Please see the updated question. Thanks.

Comment: I  check it and I think `sort_index` is not neccessary, because `reindex` 'sorts' `df1 =df1.reindex(columns=range(1,5),fill_value=0)` values to order `1,2,3,4`. So if values are different, maybe is necesary change `range(1,5)`.

Comment: Hmm, one problem ther can be - `df1 = pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(df['q6'].values.tolist()), prefix_sep='', prefix='')` return unique column names?

Comment: it returns: 1 2 1 2 (column names), where [1,2] will have: 1 2 1 2 -> 1 0 0 1, and [2,1] will have: 1 2 1 2 -> 0 1 1 0

Comment: Yes, so column names are duplicated and get error `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` ?

Comment: Ok, so need `df1 = df1.groupby(axis=1, level=0).max()` after `df1.columns = df1.columns.astype(int)`

Comment: It create unique index and aggregate by column max value (`1`)

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"q6":[[1,2],[1,2,4]]})
a = df.q6.values.tolist()
e = [np.array(x)-1 for x in a]
b = np.zeros((len(e),4))
for i in range(0, len(e)):
    b[i][e[i]] = 1
c = np.hsplit(b,4)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'q6':c[0],'q7':c[1],'q8':c[2],'q9':c[3]})
```

At the end i created other data frame with your 4 desired columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
    >>> df1
       participant_id  q1  q2  q3  q4  q5         q6              response_date  summary
    0              37   0   1   1   2   2     [1, 2]   2016-05-19T07:19:32.620Z        8
    1              37   0   1   1   2   2  [1, 2, 4]  2016-05-26T07:14:24.7130Z        8
    >>> def widen(oldQ6):
    ...     l = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    ...     for i in oldQ6:
    ...         l[int(i)-1] = 1.0
    ...     return l
    ... 
    >>> df1['q6'], df1['q7'], df1['q8'], df1['q9'] = zip(*df1['q6'].map(widen))
    >>> df1
       participant_id  q1  q2  q3  q4  q5  q6              response_date  summary  q7  q8  q9
    0              37   0   1   1   2   2   1   2016-05-19T07:19:32.620Z        8  1   0   0
    1              37   0   1   1   2   2   1  2016-05-26T07:14:24.7130Z        8  1   0   1
```